# Cannot interact with transitioning html elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

This thing is driving me mad!

I create programmatically absolutely positioned divs inside another div in an html page. The outer div is registered for `mousedown` and `touchstart` events and the inner div starts moving using css3 transitions.

All the transitions affect the `-WebKit-transform` property.

Everything works ok, except for the event handling:
In Chrome and Safari all the events are caught in the outer div event handler but the target property of the event is rarely the div I click!

When a div finishes it's transition then the event target is always the correct one, but NOT while the divs are transitioning. Is this a bug? Am I missing something?

UPDATE:

*The following sample is compatible with Safari and Chrome*

Here is an online sample that demonstrates the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/qfn7F/4/

Spheres get spawned from the top of the screen and are moving towards the bottom of it. When the user clicks on a sphere (`mousedown` event), the clicked sphere must disappear from the screen.

Here is the code that handles interactions with spheres:

```
container.addEventListener(onSelect, function() {
    if (event.target.classList.contains("transition")) {
        var tDiv = event.target;
        var box = tDiv.getBoundingClientRect();
        var durationEase = "0.25s linear";
        tDiv.style.pointerEvents = "none";
        tDiv.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(" + box.left + "px," + box.top + "px, 1px)";
        tDiv.style.opacity = 0;
        tDiv.style.webkitTransition = "opacity " + durationEase;
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
}, false);
```

BUT the target of the event is RARELY the sphere that the user clicked, so the spheres do not disappear from the screen in an consistent way.

If a sphere reaches the bottom of the screen, that is the transition ends, then the click event works 100%.

Comment: Related questions:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18629298/on-a-moving-element-dont-fire-the-mouse-events
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304215/css3-translate3d-mouse-events-issue
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472802/css-z-index-lost-after-webkit-transform-translate3d
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496551/translate3d-causing-jquery-hover-click-events-to-not-fire-correctly

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problem when animating using css3 Transform.
Intsead of using css transform use the css positions to and give transtion to animate

[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/qfn7F/15/)

```
 tDiv.style.top = (tDiv.offsetWidth * 0.5 + Math.random() * (window.innerWidth - tDiv.offsetWidth)) + "px";
 tDiv.style.right = (window.innerHeight - tDiv.offsetHeight) + "px";
```

Comment: this is not as performant as the tranform animation, because in this case the elements are not cached...

Comment: i couldn't understand the caching part. could you explain some thing about it?

Comment: If you animate an element using the transform property instead of top, left etc then the performance is much higher due to GPU acceleration. This is even true if you apply a translate3d(0,0,0) to the element and then animate the top left properties. More details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661876/css-is-transition-left-top-gpu-accelerated